# redirect domain according to extension and language

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to look for a solution for a multilanguage website. I have 4 domains:

- domain.com
- domain.be
- domain.nl
- domain.uk

According to the domain, the appropriate language has to be loaded.The language gets determined by ?lang=...
I have tried modrewrite in .htaccess but it does not suit my needs. When a user visits domain.com/page the .htaccess does not process the rules.
So I was thinking to do it with php.
Currently, the language and the cookie gets set by this piece php:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lang = 'en_eu';
}

switch ($lang) {
  case 'nl_be':
  $lang_file = 'nl_be.php';
  break;

  case 'nl_nl':
  $lang_file = 'nl_nl.php';
  break;

  case 'en_us':
  $lang_file = 'en_us.php';
  break;

  case 'en_uk':
  $lang_file = 'en_us.php';
  break;

  case 'en_eu':
  $lang_file = 'en_eu.php';
  break;

  default:
  $lang_file = 'en_eu.php';

}

include_once 'components/languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```

I was thinking to add a some lines to determine the domain name and add some if statements to determine the language according to the domain. But I don't really know how and if this is the right way of doing it.

```
<?php
$url =  "//{$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']}";

if ($url == domain.be) {
    $lang = 'nl_be';
}
elseif ($url == domain.uk) {
    $lang = 'en_uk';
}
else ( ) {
    $lang = 'en_us';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After reading this: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Google suggest keeping different language versions on their own URLs.

As you already have the top level domains, I would just check the domain name and determine the language from that.

Then at the top of each page give the users language choice links:

```
English: example.com/node/1
French:  example.fr/node/1
etc.
```

Hide the current language link.

And supplement the above with link elements in the head:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es" href="http://example.es/node/1" />
```

Comment: tlds don't seem like the natural fit for multi-language sites.  The UK has at least four spoken and written languages.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer in this thread [How to default to another language based on domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784982/how-to-default-to-another-language-based-on-domain)

It makes use of SetEnvIf in .htaccess and php handles the rest

code in .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Host "\.be$" SITE_LANGUAGE=nl_be
SetEnvIf Host "\.uk$" SITE_LANGUAGE=en_uk
```

and then call the SITE_LANGUAGE with:

```
$_SERVER['SITE_LANGUAGE'];
```

code in PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Cache-control: private'); // IE 6 FIX

$lang = $_SERVER['SITE_LANGUAGE'];

if(isSet($_GET['lang']))
{
$lang = $_GET['lang'];

// register the session and set the cookie
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;

setcookie('lang', $lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
}
else if(isSet($_SESSION['lang']))
{
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else if(isSet($_COOKIE['lang']))
{
$lang = $_COOKIE['lang'];
}
else
{
$lang = 'en_eu';
}

switch ($lang) {
  case 'nl_be':
  $lang_file = 'nl_be.php';
  break;

  case 'nl_nl':
  $lang_file = 'nl_nl.php';
  break;

  case 'en_us':
  $lang_file = 'en_us.php';
  break;

  case 'en_uk':
  $lang_file = 'en_us.php';
  break;

  case 'en_eu':
  $lang_file = 'en_eu.php';
  break;

  default:
  $lang_file = 'en_eu.php';

}

include_once 'components/languages/'.$lang_file;
?>
```