# Joomla change language in PHP (index.php) depend on domain name

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I would like to manually set language in PHP (index.php) before load the page depend on domain name. For example I need something like this:

```
<?php    
$server = filter_var($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($server == 'domain1') {
   // How can i set current language to sk-SK?
} else {
   // How can i set current language to en-GB?
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784982/how-to-default-to-another-language-based-on-domain try this...

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->setLanguage('sk-SK' );
$lang->load();
```

Comment: I was try this - nothing works:

    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $lang->setDefault('en-GB');
    $lang->setLanguage('en-GB');
    $lang->load();

    $l = JLanguage::getInstance();
    $l->setLanguage('en-GB');
    $l->setDefault('en-GB');
    $l->load();

    $app->loadLanguage(JLanguage::getInstance('en-GB'));

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom system plugin that runs `onAfterInitialize` and performs the requested task. See https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla for basic instructions on how to build a plugin.

You may want to duplicate and rename the languageFilter plugin since you were already able to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked the languagefilter plugin, now it works, but its not correct, because while updating Joomla to the new version file can be overwrite :-(